# How to run thread group forever with time delay in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a thread group with 30 Http request. I would like to run the whole thread group once with just 1 user, than wait 30 minutes, run it again, wait 30 minutes and so on for few days.
How should I configure my Thread group properties?

Thanks for you help.

Martin

Answer (score 2):

- For Thread Group nothing really special, something like:

  [image]

  Just define sufficient number of loops, either let it to run "forever" or choose the appropriate amount of iterations so it will be enough to cover your "few days"
- For the "delay" - there are 2 options:

  1. Add [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of the first request and configure it to introduce "sleep" for 30 minutes:

     [image]

     in this case the delay will be introduced **before first request**, see [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) article for more information
  2. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler after the last request

     [image]

     in this case the delay will be added after the last HTTP Request sampler

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your help, Flow Control Action did a good job ;)